# How to set OnStart script to CfnNotebookInstanceLifecycleConfigProps in java

Tags: java, aws-cdk

Google doid not help a lot and AWS documention for sagemaker-1.121.0-sources.jar!/software/amazon/awscdk/services/sagemaker/CfnNotebookInstanceLifecycleConfigProps.java:102

```
  @software.amazon.jsii.Stability(software.amazon.jsii.Stability.Level.Stable)
    public Builder onStart(java.util.List<? extends java.lang.Object> onStart) {
        this.onStart = onStart;
        return this;
    }
```

The question is: how to use OnStart in java to pass OnStart script. I'm just trying to do [similar](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-neptune-samples/blob/master/neptune-sagemaker/cloudformation-templates/neptune-workbench/neptune-workbench-stack.yaml) thing by CDK instead of directly CloudFormation and got stuck. Passing list of strings (where each item is a bash command) leads to an Exception.

Thanks in advance

```
//        the current varinal fails with
//        14:50:28.911  Error: Value did not match any type in union: Value did not match any type in union: Expected object reference, got "#!/bin/bash\n", Expected object reference, got "#!/bin/bash\n", Expected object reference, got ["#!/bin/bash\n","sudo -u ec2-user -i << 'EOF'","\n","echo 'export GRAPH_NOTEBOOK_AUTH_MODE=","DEFAULT' >> ~/.bashrc\n","echo 'export GRAPH_NOTEBOOK_HOST=${Token[TOKEN.509]} >> ~/.bashrc\n","echo 'export GRAPH_NOTEBOOK_PORT=-1.8881545897088608E289 >> ~/.bashrc\n","echo 'export NEPTUNE_LOAD_FROM_S3_ROLE_ARN=${Token[TOKEN.828]} >> ~/.bashrc\n"," aws s3 cp s3://aws-neptune-notebook/graph_notebook.tar.gz /tmp/graph_notebook.tar.gz","\n","rm -rf /tmp/graph_notebook","\n","tar -zxvf /tmp/graph_notebook.tar.gz -C /tmp","\n","/tmp/graph_notebook/install.sh","\n","EOF"]
//        14:50:28.911      at Kernel._toSandbox (/tmp/jsii-java-runtime3941392201016558027/lib/program.js:8726:23)
//        14:50:28.911      at /tmp/jsii-java-runtime3941392201016558027/lib/program.js:9283:37
//        14:50:28.911      at mapValues (/tmp/jsii-java-runtime3941392201016558027/lib/program.js:9554:35)
//        14:50:28.911      at Object.deserialize (/tmp/jsii-java-runtime3941392201016558027/lib/program.js:9279:28)
//        14:50:28.911      at Kernel._toSandbox (/tmp/jsii-java-runtime3941392201016558027/lib/program.js:8718:69)
//        14:50:28.911      at /tmp/jsii-java-runtime3941392201016558027/lib/program.js:8766:42
//        14:50:28.911      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
//        14:50:28.911      at Kernel._boxUnboxParameters (/tmp/jsii-java-runtime3941392201016558027/lib/program.js:8766:27)
//        14:50:28.911      at Kernel._toSandboxValues (/tmp/jsii-java-runtime3941392201016558027/lib/program.js:8752:29)
//        14:50:28.911      at /tmp/jsii-java-runtime3941392201016558027/lib/program.js:8367:75
//        14:50:28.911      at software.amazon.jsii.JsiiRuntime.processErrorResponse (JsiiRuntime.java:124)
//        14:50:28.911      at software.amazon.jsii.JsiiRuntime.requestResponse (JsiiRuntime.java:95)
//        14:50:28.911      at software.amazon.jsii.JsiiClient.createObject (JsiiClient.java:89)
//        14:50:28.911      at software.amazon.jsii.JsiiEngine.createNewObject (JsiiEngine.java:603)
//        14:50:28.911      at software.amazon.awscdk.services.sagemaker.CfnNotebookInstanceLifecycleConfig.<init> (CfnNotebookInstanceLifecycleConfig.java:33)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CfnNotebookInstanceLifecycleConfig.NotebookInstanceLifecycleHookProperty

```
var lifeCycleOnStartHook = CfnNotebookInstanceLifecycleConfig.NotebookInstanceLifecycleHookProperty.builder()
                                                                                                     .content(
                                                                                                               Fn.base64(onStartCommand)
                                                                                                       )
                                                                                                       .build();
    var lcBuilder = CfnNotebookInstanceLifecycleConfigProps.builder()
                                                           .onStart(List.of(lifeCycleOnStartHook))
```